# How do I timestamp every ping result?

Tags: bash, osx-lion, ping, bsd

[Ping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_%28networking_utility%29) returns this by default:

```
64 bytes from 203.173.50.132: icmp_seq=0 ttl=244 time=57.746 ms
```

Is there some way I can get it to add the timestamp?

For example,

```
Mon 21 May 2012 15:15:37 EST | 64 bytes from 203.173.50.132: icmp_seq=0 ttl=244 time=57.746 ms
```

I'm on OS X v10.7 (Lion) which seems to have some [BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution) version of ping.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

On OS X you can simply use the --apple-time option:

```
ping -i 2 --apple-time www.apple.com
```

Produces results like:

```
10:09:55.691216 64 bytes from 72.246.225.209: icmp_seq=0 ttl=60 time=34.388 ms
10:09:57.687282 64 bytes from 72.246.225.209: icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=25.319 ms
10:09:59.729998 64 bytes from 72.246.225.209: icmp_seq=2 ttl=60 time=64.097 ms
```

Comment: This doesn't handle timeouts.

Answer (score 155):

I could not redirect the Perl based solution to a file for some reason so I kept searching and found a `bash` only way to do this:

`ping www.google.fr | while read pong; do echo "$(date): $pong"; done`

```
Wed Jun 26 13:09:23 CEST 2013: PING www.google.fr (173.194.40.56) 56(84) bytes of data.
Wed Jun 26 13:09:23 CEST 2013: 64 bytes from zrh04s05-in-f24.1e100.net (173.194.40.56): icmp_req=1 ttl=57 time=7.26 ms
Wed Jun 26 13:09:24 CEST 2013: 64 bytes from zrh04s05-in-f24.1e100.net (173.194.40.56): icmp_req=2 ttl=57 time=8.14 ms
```

The credit goes to https://askubuntu.com/a/137246

Comment: This doesn't appear to work on debian wheezy. Just stays there without output until ctrl+c

Comment: @KBeezie Not sure what the problem was in your case. I've just tried it on debian wheezy and it worked fine. Are you using `bash` as your shell?

Comment: I actually like this approach much better as it does not use perl or awk.

Comment: To also see the timeouts, all that is needed is to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` before the pipe (`|`), like so: `ping $host 2>&1 | while read pong; do echo "$(date): $pong"; done`. If you wish to write (or append) that to a file, you can redirect the whole command (after the done). Also, if you wish not to spawn a subshell, the `date` command supports `echo`ing arbitrary input, like so: `ping $host 2>&1 | while read pong; do date "+%c: $pong"; done`. Please note that the `format` argument of `date` (that starts with `+`) can be customized at will. See `man date` for further information.

Comment: FWIW, my default shell is ZSH and it wasn't working. When I ran it in Bash it worked fine. OP does mention that in the first paragraph of his comment... :)

Comment: @richk there is nothing really bash specific about this, it should work in posix shells. works in the public domain korn shell.

Comment: Here is the fish version: `ping google.fr | while read pong; echo (date)": $pong"; end`

Comment: this is so helpful. i am also teeing the output like so: `ping -i 5 google.com | while read pong; do echo "$(date): $pong" | tee -a uptime.log; done`

Answer (score 81):

If your AWK doesn't have `strftime()`:

```
ping host | perl -nle 'print scalar(localtime), " ", $_'
```

To redirect it to a file, use standard shell redirection and turn off output buffering:

```
ping host | perl -nle 'BEGIN {$|++} print scalar(localtime), " ", $_' > outputfile
```

If you want ISO8601 format for the timestamp:

```
ping host | perl -nle 'use Time::Piece; BEGIN {$|++} print localtime->datetime, " ", $_' > outputfile
```

Comment: although i removed the 'bytes from' filter since I want the timestamps on every line... especially the timeouts.

Comment: Works well, but it suppresses STDERR for the summary results at the end when you press Control+C.  Same issue exists for the BASH answer.

Comment: @NicholasBlasgen: That's because the Ctrl-C goes to the last process in the pipe and the `ping` only receives a `SIGPIPE`. You can use process substitution instead of a pipe: `ping host > >(perl -nle 'print scalar(localtime), " ", $_')` and the Ctrl-C will go to `ping` and do what you want. You can do the same thing with the `while` loop. By the way, on my system the summary goes to `STDOUT` rather than `STDERR` (so it gets timestamped, too).

Comment: This answer would be much better, IMHO, if the datetime format was in ISO8601.

Comment: @Phrogz: I agree that that's a more desirable format, but my answer comes close to matching what the OP asked for (depending on locale). To get ISO8601 format you can `use Time::Piece; print localtime->datetime` (and other appropriate settings) starting with 5.10 or use a CPAN module or `strftime`.

Comment: Great point about the OP's format! And thanks for including the iso8601 equivalent.

Answer (score 37):

From `man ping`:

```
   -D     Print timestamp (unix time + microseconds as in gettimeofday) before each line.
```

It will produce something like this:

```
[1337577886.346622] 64 bytes from 4.2.2.2: icmp_req=1 ttl=243 time=47.1 ms
```

Then timestamp could be parsed out from the `ping` response and converted to the required format with `date`.

Comment: sorry. adsl dropped out as I was adding tags... it's OSX Lion - doesn't have a "-D" option :-(

Comment: someone good with perl and regex could pipe this to format to a human readable date time =]

Answer (score 22):

1. terminal output:

   `ping -i 5 google.com | xargs -L 1 -I '{}' date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S: {}'`
2. file output:

   `ping -i 5 google.com | xargs -L 1 -I '{}' date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S: {}' > test.txt`
3. terminal + file output:

   `ping -i 5 google.com | xargs -L 1 -I '{}' date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S: {}' | tee test.txt`
4. file output background:

   `nohup ping -i 5 google.com | xargs -L 1 -I '{}' date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S: {}' > test.txt &`

Answer (score 14):

My original submission was incorrect because it did not evaluate date for each line. Corrections have been made.

Try this

```
 ping google.com | xargs -L 1 -I '{}' date '+%+: {}'
```

produces the following output

```
Thu Aug 15 10:13:59 PDT 2013: PING google.com (74.125.239.103): 56 data bytes
Thu Aug 15 10:13:59 PDT 2013: 64 bytes from 74.125.239.103: icmp_seq=0 ttl=55 time=14.983 ms
Thu Aug 15 10:14:00 PDT 2013: 64 bytes from 74.125.239.103: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=17.340 ms
Thu Aug 15 10:14:01 PDT 2013: 64 bytes from 74.125.239.103: icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=15.898 ms
Thu Aug 15 10:14:02 PDT 2013: 64 bytes from 74.125.239.103: icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=15.720 ms
Thu Aug 15 10:14:03 PDT 2013: 64 bytes from 74.125.239.103: icmp_seq=4 ttl=55 time=16.899 ms
Thu Aug 15 10:14:04 PDT 2013: 64 bytes from 74.125.239.103: icmp_seq=5 ttl=55 time=16.242 ms
Thu Aug 15 10:14:05 PDT 2013: 64 bytes from 74.125.239.103: icmp_seq=6 ttl=55 time=16.574 ms
```

The -L 1 option causes xargs to process one line at a time instead of words.

Comment: Doesn't print during periods of 'Request timeout'; saves them all up and they get dumped with the same timestamp when request timeouts stop.

Comment: @DavidEison try `ping -D -n -O -i1 -W1 8.8.8.8`

Answer (score 11):

On macos you can do

`ping --apple-time 127.0.0.1`

The output looks like

```
16:07:11.315419 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.064 ms
16:07:12.319933 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.157 ms
16:07:13.322766 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.066 ms
16:07:14.324649 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.148 ms
16:07:15.328743 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.092 ms
```

Comment: This approach does seem to work okay for replies, but the timestamp is excluded for timeouts.

Answer (score 11):

The simpler option is just using [`ts(1)`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/moreutils/ts.1.en.html) from moreutils (fairly standard on most distros).

```
$ ping 1.1.1.1 | ts 

Feb 13 12:49:17 PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data. 
Feb 13 12:49:17 64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=5.92 ms
Feb 13 12:49:18 64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=5.30 ms
Feb 13 12:49:19 64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=5.71 ms
Feb 13 12:49:20 64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=57 time=5.86 ms
```

or

```
 ping 1.1.1.1 -I eth0 | ts "[%FT%X]"
```

Allows for the same strftime format strings as the shell/`date` workaround.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
ping www.google.com | while read endlooop; do echo "$(date): $endlooop"; done
```

It returns something like:

```
Wednesday 18 January  09:29:20 AEDT 2017: PING www.google.com (216.58.199.36) 56(84) bytes of data.
Wednesday 18 January  09:29:20 AEDT 2017: 64 bytes from syd09s12-in-f36.1e100.net (216.58.199.36): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=2.86 ms
Wednesday 18 January  09:29:21 AEDT 2017: 64 bytes from syd09s12-in-f36.1e100.net (216.58.199.36): icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=2.64 ms
Wednesday 18 January  09:29:22 AEDT 2017: 64 bytes from syd09s12-in-f36.1e100.net (216.58.199.36): icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=2.76 ms
Wednesday 18 January  09:29:23 AEDT 2017: 64 bytes from syd09s12-in-f36.1e100.net (216.58.199.36): icmp_seq=4 ttl=57 time=1.87 ms
Wednesday 18 January  09:29:24 AEDT 2017: 64 bytes from syd09s12-in-f36.1e100.net (216.58.199.36): icmp_seq=5 ttl=57 time=2.45 ms
```

Answer (score 4):

Pipe the result to `awk`:

```
 ping host | awk '{if($0 ~ /bytes from/){print strftime()"|"$0}else print}'
```

Comment: has promise! doesn't like the strftime so i'm working on that

Comment: Check this code with a non existing host or when the net is down, I'm not happy with this result ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a function in your `~/.bashrc` file, so you get a ping command `ping-t` on your console:

```
function ping-t { ping "$1" | while read pong; do echo "$(date): $pong"; done; }
```

Now you can call this on the console:

```
ping-t example.com
```

> Sa 31. Mär 12:58:31 CEST 2018: PING example.com (93.184.216.34) 56(84) bytes of data.
>   Sa 31. Mär 12:58:31 CEST 2018: 64 bytes from 93.184.216.34 (93.184.216.34): icmp_seq=1 ttl=48 time=208 ms
>   Sa 31. Mär 12:58:32 CEST 2018: 64 bytes from 93.184.216.34 (93.184.216.34): icmp_seq=2 ttl=48 time=233 ms

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify any time stamp or interval for how long you would require such output, so I considered it to be an infinite loop. You can change it accordingly as per your need.

```
while true
do
   echo -e "`date`|`ping -n -c 1 <IP_TO_PING>|grep 'bytes from'`"
   sleep 2
done
```

Comment: You should change the `grep` part to ` `egrep '(bytes from|errors)'`

Comment: @rubo77 Can you elaborate why to use 'egrep' instead of 'grep'

Comment: egrep only to add a regular expression to get an output for errors too

Answer (score 1):

```
ping -D -n -O -i1 -W1 8.8.8.8
```

or maybe

```
while true; do \
    ping -n -w1 -W1 -c1 8.8.8.8 \
    | grep -E "rtt|100%" \
    | sed -e "s/^/`date` /g"; \
    sleep 1; \
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I also need this to monitor the network issue for my database mirroring time out issue. I use the command code as below:

```
ping -t Google.com|cmd /q /v /c "(pause&pause)>nul & for /l %a in () do (set /p "data=" && echo(!date! !time! !data!)&ping -n 2 Google.com>nul" >C:\pingtest.txt
```

You just need to modify Google.com to your server name. It works perfectly for me. and remember to stop this when you finished. The pingtest.txt file will increase by 1 KB per second (around).

Thank for raymond.cc. https://www.raymond.cc/blog/timestamp-ping-with-hrping/

Comment: Update: The pingtest.txt file will increase by 4.5 KB per min (around).

Answer (score 0):

Try this line.

```
while sleep 1;do echo "$(date +%d-%m-%y-%T) $(ping -c 1 whatever.com | gawk 'FNR==2{print "Response from:",$4,$8}')" | tee -a /yourfolder/pingtest.log;done
```

You'll have to cancel it with `ctrl-c` tho.

Comment: good idea with using `tee`, but the problem with `-c 1` is losing the overall stats...

Answer (score -1):

just use sed and loop:

```
ping google.com|while read; do sed -r "s/(.*)/$(date) \1/g"<<<"$REPLY";done
```

Comment: Does not work because it only ever gets the timestamp from the start of the command.

Comment: Updated my answer. Really need to rerun sed for each separate line, so I have added loop for that.